Extracting with regex two conditions of some text
My code doesn't work:
 regexp_substr('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. consectetur', '([^(.|()]+)|((.){0,9})')

The text should end with a dot, and if it does not have a dot, then it should have a maximum of 10 characters. Is it even possible to do this?
Two examples text:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. consectetur
Donec quis turpis sed sapien ullamcorper viverra sodales a est

This is what it should look like

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Donec quis


You can use a replacing approach here:
REGEXP_REPLACE('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. consectetur',
                      '^([^.]+)\..*|^(.{10}).*',
                      '\1\2') 

See this regex demo.
Details:

^([^.]+)\..* - if a string has a dot, capture the text before it, and then match the dot with the rest of the string:

^ - start of string
([^.]+) - Group 1 (\1): any one or more chars other than .
\. - a dot
.* - any zero or more chars as many as possible


| - or
^(.{10}).* - match and capture (into Group 2) the 10 chars ((.{10})) at the beginning of the string (^), then match the rest of the string.

The replacement is two backreferences to the captured values.

When there is a leading dot, this does not give the expected output. You want '^([^.]*)\..*|^(.{10}).*' or '^(.*?)\..*$|^(.{10}).*$' fiddle.

@MT0 I expect the inputs to contain non-empty sentences. In case there are leading dots, I'd rather expect them to be ignored: '^\.*([^.]+)\..*|^(.{10}).*' or - if empty values are really expected - '^\.*([^.]*)\..*|^(.{10}).*'

You do not need a regular expression and can use simple string functions and a CASE expression:
SELECT SUBSTR(
         value,
         1,
         CASE WHEN INSTR(value, '.') > 0 THEN INSTR(value, '.') - 1 ELSE 10 END
       ) AS result
FROM   table_name;

If you want to use a regular expression then you can use:
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         value,
         '^(.*?)\..*$|^(.{0,10}).*$',
         '\1\2'
       )  AS result
FROM   table_name;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. consectetur' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Donec quis turpis sed sapien ullamcorper viverra sodales a est' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '.ABCDEFGHIJKLM' FROM DUAL;

Both output:



RESULT




Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet


Donec quis


ABC


null



fiddle
